# Android Studio Sqlite backup data before creating new when dbversion is higher

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, backup

I'm facing a little problem when I make changes to my sqlite database rows and then I increment database version. Database is created again next run time. Is there a build in way to take all old data out before and then insert old data again to their corresponding table rows.

Comment: Can you show your onUpdate method? It seems that you are droping the table and creating again, but you can update the database without droping it

Comment: Wait what.. I'll post my code soon!